# Python not catching TypeError exception with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm not sure how to handle this exception anymore. This is the problematic codeblock. `csre` and `csre_err` are compiled regex patterns. I am trying to catch the exception twice, but neither one actually catches the exception. I am trying to at least find an example of the problematic item["notes"], as far as I know they are all strings, but I can't catch it.

```
try:
    mongoj[id_]["notes"] = item["notes"]
    try:
        if csre.search(item['notes']) is not None:
            if csre_err.search(item['notes']) is not None:
                pass
            else:
                mongoj[id_]["container"] = csre.search(item['notes']).group(0)
    except TypeError:
        print item['notes']
except (KeyError,TypeError):
    mongoj[id_]["notes"] = None
```

I am still getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-97-09b4e442a24e> in <module>()
     281         mongoj[id_]["notes"] = item["notes"]
     282         try:
 --> 283             if csre.search(item['notes']) is not None:
     284                 if csre_err.search(item['notes']) is not None:
     285                     pass

 TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: are you running the code with a debugger?

Comment: No, i'm using an ipython notebook though. Have never needed a debugger before with a notebook.

Comment: Can you boil it down to a self-contained example that doesn't rely on external data?